# I was a middle sister

Tags: riddle, history

> Both of my siblings served in a war, in which the younger one got
>   killed.
>
> I knew the richest people in the world.  But also the poor.
>
> I died young, on a cold night.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are

> The Titanic

Both of my siblings served in a war, in which the younger one got killed.

> The Titanic had two sister ships, the RMS Olympic and the HMHS Britannic, both of which were requisitioned by the British government for use in World War I. The younger Britannic struck a mine in 1916 and sunk in the Kea Channel.

I knew the richest people in the world. But also the poor.

> The Titanic's passengers included some of the wealthiest people in the world as well as hundreds of very poor emigrants.

I died young, on a cold night.

> The Titanic famously struck an iceberg and sank on its maiden voyage.

Answer (score 6):

You could be:

> **Cleopatra**
>
>  She had two brothers: Ptolemy XIII, who died in the Alexandrian war, and Ptolemy XIV, who she had assassinated later. She died at age 39, and as a rich queen herself, certainly knew the richest(Caesar, Mark Antony) and likely the poorest people of her kingdom.

Comment: @Abigail Well many deserts do get cold at night! ;-)

Comment: @Abigail, not only that, but she was also older than both her brothers. I forgot about the title (although technically she was the middle of 6 siblings). Plus I am not sure that her second brother served in that war. Oh well, at least we learned some EgyptoRoman history along the way. E.g. I didn't know she was successively married to both her brothers, and that this wasn't unusual; it was standard practice for pharaohs - to "keep the royal lineage pure". Her mother was also her cousin. Or that she was actually Cleopatra *VII*, with multiple less significant namesakes that came before her.